# How to type faster on a tablet computer?

Tags: technology

I am fast at typing on keyboards and even phone screens but find it hard to keep pace on tablet computers. Could someone advice me for the same?

Comment: With predictive text? Or with voice recognition?

Comment: With an external keyboard -- Bluetooth, USB etc.

Answer (score 1):

I use a case with a thin keyboard for my tablet.  I find typing on the screen horribly slow so I activate the keyboard case when I have to type a lot.  When I'm done I deactivate the keyboard case so I can hold the tablet or set it on a surface and not care about whether the keys are pressed or not.

If you are fast at typing on a phone keyboard you may find an app like Remote Mouse useful ... it apparently allows you to use an iPhone keyboard as input to an iPad.  (I haven't used it.)  There are probably many other similar apps on the Apple app store.  There must be similar apps for Android.

Answer (score 0):

You can connect an external keyboard via Bluetooth or USB.

Or you can use the touch screen and try to enable Swype which should aid you with typing.